# Centered content box scrolling on whole body

Tags: html, css, layout

I would like to build a layout as shown below.
The main goal is to have a center area with the content that scrolls with the scrollbar of the whole body.

[image]

I figured out a solution ([JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juerg/nuo9cz0b/)) consisting of two layers with different z-index. The upper one containig the border (in white) and the lower one containing the content (in gray).

```
HTML
<body>
  <div class="contentcontainer">
    <div class="middlecontainer">
      <div class="center content" onclick="alert('click on content')">
        <h1 onclick="alert('click on content header');"> content</h1>
        <div onclick="alert('click on content body');">Lorem ipsum    dolor sit amet,...
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="bordercontainer">
   <div class="header" onclick="alert('click on header');"></div>
     <div class="middlecontainer">
       <div class="left">
         <ul>
           <li>navigation 1</li>
           <li>navigation 2</li>
           <li>navigation 3</li>
         </ul>
       </div>
       <div class="center"></div>
       <div class="right"></div>
     </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>
</body>


CSS
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: MuseoSans-300;
    font-size: 24px;
}

ul {
    padding: 20px;
}

li {
   list-style-type: none;
}

.contentcontainer {
    position: relative;
    display:flex;
    top:100px;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.bordercontainer {
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.header {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100px;
}

.left {
   background-color: white;
   flex: 1 0 100px;
}

.middlecontainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.center {
    opacity: 1;
    flex: 0 0 300px; 
}

.content {
    margin: auto;
    background-color:rgb(71, 89, 98);
    color: white;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.right {   
    background-color: white;
    flex: 1 0 100px;
}

.footer {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100px;
}
```

I'm facing two main problems:

1. Events attached to the lower layer (content) do not fire (e.g. on the title of the content).
2. It's quite complicated. The content will containt a lot of logic that will also have to interact with the outher part (e.g. Navigation). I also fear lots of layout issues once the whole application gets more complicated.

I'm pretty sure there must be a simpler way to achive this kind of a layout. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can work around it using `.bordercontainer { pointer-events: none; }`.
2. Looks like typical CSS complexity to me for a non trivial task :D

Comment: thanks a lot! setting pointer-events on the right places does the trick. About the CSS complexity still not convinced that this is the ideal solution for the problem. For that reason I leave the question open for a while to see if anyone else has an idea on how to solve it.

Comment: @tschuege, has it been a while yet? :)